# Запись дынных в глобальный state или Context после fetch (react hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь решить проблему:
Реализовал post-запрос на REST-сервер с помощью fetch. Получаю данные и далее, с помощью функции в Context, сохраняю объекты в context, чтобы использовать его в двух разных компонентах. Однако после записи данных в context из fetch происходят аномальные действия: страница как будто полностью ререндерится. Это происходит после каждого нажатия на товар.

Вот скрины из profiler:

Название Context - `ProductProvider`

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### ProductProvider:

```js
function ProductsProvider(props) {
    
    //states
    const [states, setStates] = useState({
        products: [],
        basketProducts: [],
        totalPrice: "0.0"
    });
   

    //Functions
    const setProducts = (products) => {
        setStates(prevState => ({...prevState, products: products}));
    };

    const setTotalPrice = (totalPrice) => {
        setStates(prevState => ({...prevState, totalPrice: totalPrice}));
    };

    const setBasketProducts = (basketProducts) => {
        setStates(prevState => ({...prevState, basketProducts: basketProducts}));
    }

    const setAllParameters = (products, basketProducts, totalPrice) => {
        if(!products) products = states.products;
        if(!basketProducts) basketProducts = states.basketProducts;
        if(!totalPrice) totalPrice = states.totalPrice;

        setStates({
            products: products,
            basketProducts: basketProducts,
            totalPrice: totalPrice
        })
    }

    const state = {
        states,

        setProducts,

        setBasketProducts,

        setTotalPrice,

        setAllParameters,
    }

    return (
        <ProductsContext.Provider value={state}>
            {props.children}
        </ProductsContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default ProductsProvider;
```

#### IncrDecrButtons:

```js
function IncrDecrButtons(props) {

    const [cookie] = useCookies();
    const {setAllParameters} = useContext(ProductsContext);

    const increaseQuantity = (product) => {
        product.quantity +=1;
        const newProductPromise = _changeProductQuantity(product);

        if(newProductPromise !== null)
            newProductPromise.then(res => {
                setAllParameters(
                    res.productList,
                    res.productList.filter(product => {
                        return !!product.quantity;
                    }),
                    res.totalPrice
                )


            }).catch(() => {console.log("error2");});
    }


    const decreaseQuantity = (product) => {
        product.quantity -=1;
        const newProductPromise = _changeProductQuantity(product);
        if(newProductPromise !== null)
            newProductPromise.then(res => {

                setAllParameters(
                    res.productList,
                    res.productList.filter(product => {
                        return !!product.quantity;
                    }),
                    res.totalPrice
                )
            }).catch();
    }

    function _changeProductQuantity(product) {
        return fetchDataJSON(
            process.env.REACT_APP_SPRING_SERVER_PATH,
            'POST',
            JSON.stringify({
                "productId": product.id,
                "quantity": product.quantity
            })
        )
    }

    function fetchDataJSON(URL, method, body) {
        return fetch(URL,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: body
            })
            .then(_handleResponseJSON)
            .catch(_handleResponseError)
    }

    function _handleResponseError(err){
        return Promise.reject(err.message);
    }

    function _handleResponseJSON(response){
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
        }
    }



    return (
        <div className={styles.incDecrButtons}>
            <button className={[styles.button, styles.button_oval, styles.incDecrButtons__button].join(" ")}
                    onClick={() => {decreaseQuantity(props.product)}}>
                <span className={[styles.button__text, styles.text, styles.text_noSelect].join(" ")}>-</span>
            </button>

            <span className={[styles.text, styles.text_paragraph, styles.text_noSelect].join(" ")}>
                {props.product.quantity}
            </span>

            <button className={[styles.button, styles.button_oval, styles.incDecrButtons__button].join(" ")}
                    onClick={() => increaseQuantity(props.product)}>
                <span className={[styles.button__text, styles.text, styles.text_noSelect].join(" ")}>+</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default IncrDecrButtons;
```

*Если нужно уточнение вопроса - пишите об этом в комментарии*

Comment: если ProductProvider в корне дерева, то да, его стейт меняется, он рендерится, и вседети по дефолту тоже. Это можно оптимизировать через `React.memo`

Comment: и по другому можно, позже может гляну

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Супер! ProductProvider находится не в корне дерева. Где-то в середине. На скриншоте данная вещь присутствует

Answer (score 1):

Eсли стейт `ProductProvider`-a меняется, то он рендерится, и все потомки (по дереву) по дефолту тоже. Это можно оптимизировать.

Если этот рендер не сказывается негативно на производительности на целевых устройствах и объемах данных, оптимизацию можно отложить.

Оптимизировать можно оборачивая некоторые компоненты в `React.memo`, чтобы отключить ререндер ветки, если пропы компонента не изменились.

Однако, если контекст поменялся, `useContext` в компоненте ведет к рендеру.
Уменьшить количество охватываемых компонент можно разделив контекст на несколько меньших контекстов.

Можно использовать в провайдере (между стейтом и контекстом) `useMemo` и `useCallback` с зависимостями.

Принимая новый список продуктов, можно вычислять реальный diff, и оставлять в списке старые объекты. В js нет встроенного сравнения по содержимому.